# Change /home directory to previously installed /home path

Tags: 22.04, home-directory

I have previously installed Ubuntu `/home` in HDD, but in new installation there is a new home directory. How to change it to the previous `/home` directory. in HDD? Could I replace new home with my old home, or do I need to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04?

Previously installed `/home` directory:

[image: previously installed /home directory]

Newly installed `/home` directory:

[image: newly installed /home directory]

Comment: @graham kind of yes. you can undertand what im asking in the question. i updated with screenshots

Comment: You don't need to re-install; you can just *adjust* the system's *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) to match what you actually want. If you create something that causes another to *shadow* an existing directory; the system will do that automatically (*meaning some data may not be seen; but you can always `umount` to remove, access it when required*).  FYI: Screenshots of text are hard to read; so just add to your *fstab* whatever arrangement you want.

Answer (score -1):

A user's `HOME` directory is specified in `/etc/passwd` and can be changed there.

Read `man 5 passwd;man sudoedit`

Once you've changed it, logoff and login to make ot take effect.